# One direction of Prokhorov theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I' trying to prove one direction of Prokhorov theorem. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

---

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{P} :=\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set all Borel probability measures on $X$. Let $d_P$ be the [Prokhorov metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434016/can-prokhorov-metric-be-extended-to-all-non-negative-finite-borel-measures) on $\mathcal{P}$. The set $\Gamma \subseteq \mathcal P$ is called *uniformly tight* if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that
$$
\mu(K^c) := \mu(X\setminus K) \le \varepsilon \quad \forall \mu \in \Gamma.
$$

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is complete separable, then [$\Gamma$ is relatively compact] implies [$\Gamma$ is uniformly tight].

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Lemma 1:* If $\{U_1, U_2,\ldots\}$ is a countable cover of $X$ and $\Gamma$ relatively compact, then
> $$
> \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists k \ge 1, \forall \mu \in \Gamma: \mu \left ( \bigg ( \bigcup_{i=1}^k  U_i \bigg )^c  \right ) < \varepsilon.
> $$

*Proof:* Assume the contrary. Let $F_k := ( \bigcup_{i=1}^kU_i )^c$ .Then
$$
\exists \varepsilon>0, \forall k \ge 1, \exists\mu_k \in \Gamma: \mu_k \left (F_k  \right ) > \varepsilon.
$$

There is a subsequence $(\mu_{\varphi (m)})$ and $\bar \mu \in \overline \Gamma$ such that $\mu_{\varphi (m)} \to \bar \mu$ in $d_P$. This implies $\mu_{\varphi (m)} \to \bar \mu$ weakly. Notice that $F_k$ is closed, so
$$
\varepsilon \le \lim\sup_m \mu_{\varphi (m)} \left ( F_k  \right ) \le \bar \mu \left ( F_k  \right ) \quad \forall k \ge 1.
$$

Notice that $F_k \searrow \emptyset$, so $\varepsilon \le 0$ which is a contradiction.

---

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Let $D := \{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. By *Lemma 1*, for each $m\ge 1$, there is $k_m$ such that
$$
\mu \left( \left [ \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_{m}} B\left(a_{i}, 1 / m \right) \right ]^c \right) < \varepsilon 2^{-m} \quad \forall \mu \in \Gamma.
$$

Take
$$
K := \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_{m}} \overline B\left(a_{i}, 1 / m \right).
$$

Then $K$ is closed and totally bounded. Hence $K$ is complete and totally bounded. So $K$ is compact. Moreover,
$$
\mu(K^c) \le \varepsilon \sum_{m=1}^\infty 2^{-m} = \varepsilon \quad \forall \mu \in \Gamma.
$$

It follows that $\Gamma$ is tight.