# If $c_n \nearrow c$ then $\lim_n \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c_n d\pi = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d\pi$

Tags: metric-spaces, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transport, polish-spaces

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $c:X \times Y \to \mathbb [0, +\infty]$ lower semi-continuous. Let $(c_n)$ with $c_n:X \times Y \to \mathbb [0, \infty)$  be a non-decreasing sequence of bounded continuous functions such that $c_n \nearrow c$. We fix Borel probability measures (b.p.m.) $\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$. Let $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ be the collection of b.p.m.'s on $X \times Y$ with marginals $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$.

> Then
> $$
> \lim_n \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c_n d\pi =:A = B:= \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d\pi.
> $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
A &= \sup_n \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c_n d\pi \\
&\le \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \sup_n \int c_n d\pi \\
&= \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d\pi \\
&=B.
\end{align}

Let's prove the converse. There is
$$
\pi_n \in \operatorname{argmin}_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c_n d \pi \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Because $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440605/let-x-y-be-polish-spaces-and-mu-nu-borel-probability-measures-on-x-y-t) uniformly tight and weak* closed, so $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is weak* compact by Prokhorov theorem. Then there is $\pi^* \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$ such that $\pi_n \to \pi^*$ weakly. First, we prove that
$$
\lim_n\int c_n d\pi_n \ge \int c_{N} d \pi^* \quad \forall N \in \mathbb N. 
$$

Indeed,
$$
\int c_n d\pi_n - \int c_{N} d \pi^* = \int (c_n - c_{N}) d\pi_n + \int c_{N} d(\pi_n- \pi^*).
$$

Then
\begin{align}
\lim_n \int c_n d\pi_n - \int c_{N} d \pi^* &= \lim_n\int (c_n - c_{N}) d\pi_n + \lim_n \int c_{N} d(\pi_n- \pi^*) \\
&= \lim_n\int (c_n - c_{N}) d\pi_n \\
&\ge 0 \quad \text{because} \quad c_n \nearrow c.
\end{align}

It follows that
$$
A=\lim_n\int c_n d\pi_n \ge \lim_N \int c_{N} d \pi^* = \int c d\pi^* \ge B. 
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: I think you can extend the result to the case where $c_n$ is only l.s.c. and bounded from below. By [Portmanteau theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441161/portmanteau-theorem-with-lower-semi-continuous-and-bounded-from-below-functions),
$$
\begin{align*}
\liminf_n \int c_n d\pi_n - \int c_{N} d \pi^* &\ge \liminf_n\int (c_n - c_{N}) d\pi_n + \liminf_n \int c_{N} d(\pi_n- \pi^*) \\
&\ge \liminf_n\int (c_n - c_{N}) d\pi_n  + 0\\
&\ge 0 \quad \text{because} \quad c_n \nearrow c.
\end{align*}
$$